# recursive search method needs while running the second time, the double amount of time

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I've got a little problem. I programmed a winforms application that recursivly searches files in a specified folder and its subfolders. When i run the application the first time the method needs 10 minutes for finding 100'000 files, but then when i execute the search-method a second time (without closing and reopening the windows form) it needs the double amount of time. why do it takes the double amount of time?

edit: first searchrun: 10 min, second run: 20 min, third run 40 min...

here my search-method:

```
        public void dirsearch(string sdir)
        {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressBar.Refresh();
            dataGridView.Refresh();
            // runs on UI thread
        });
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdir))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(f, searchPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        {
                            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(f);
                            string fileName = file.Name;
                            string filePath = f;
                            string user = File.GetAccessControl(filePath).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
                            properties.Add(new FileProperties(file.Name, f, file.Length, file.LastWriteTime));
                            //dataGridView.Refresh();
                            //progressBar.Refresh();
                        tryagainpoint:
                            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("insert into Attribute (Dateiname, Dateipfad, Dateierstellungsdatum, Dateiendung, Grösse, Ersteller, Letztes_mal_bearbeitet, FS) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, '{5}', '{6}', {7})", file.Name, f, file.CreationTime, file.Extension, file.Length, user, file.LastWriteTime, ID);
                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (OleDbException)
                            {
                                if (file.Name.Contains(@"'"))
                                {
                                    fileName = file.Name.Replace(@"'", @"''");
                                    filePath = f.Replace(@"'", @"''");
                                    goto tryagainpoint;
                                }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                file = null;
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    dirsearch(d);
                    progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
                }

                catch (Exception exc) //Schreibt geworfene Exception in logfile.txt
                {
                    WriteExceptionIntoTxtFile(exc);
                    continue;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is with properties object? and more you should use Parameters with the insert statement ( get rid off go to )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you clear collection "properties" between the two calls. If not, this collection will contain 100,000 entries at the beginning of the second call to that function and contain 200,000 at the end. There is a performance issue with the data grid when you use grouping!

BTW: the code would be faster, if you don't refresh datagrid and progressbar after each found file!

Comment: yes i clear the properties collection between the two calls. the refresh is for the end-user, so he see's that somethings working.

Comment: i corrected the mistake withe the refresh after each found file, now it's a bit faster, but it still takes the double amount of time in the second run.

Comment: Is grouping activated in gridview?

Comment: wir können auch deutsch schreiben, ich habe den delegate rausgenommen, nun braucht er nurnoch 4 minuten im ersten Lauf, und 6 minuten im zweiten Lauf, lasse das Programm nun noch ein drittes Mal laufen. Das Programm ist jetzt zwar schneller nur kriegt der User gar nichts davon mit das die Suche läuft.

Comment: es lag am delegate, Suchmethode hatte beim dritten Lauf 5 minuten :)

Comment: Great! But remember, this is a international platform, so posting in english is recommended. Only then everyone can make an effort reading the discussion!

Comment: So what is the right answer? OP was already clearing properties, right?